# Wrong comparison of string and char*

Tags: c, string, string-comparison

My program gets an input from a port and then I send this string to be check against a few strings. I first tried to compare, java style, only using "myString" but I got a 13 (thirteen) when comparing. I thought it was because I should use a char pointer, but I still get 13. Then I saw that the buffer was passed with a new line, so I added \n but I got 3 (Three). From here I dont know how to reduce it to 0. It has to be something how I am passing the string.

Getting the string:

```
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
if (n < 0) 
    error("ERROR reading from socket");
printf("String at start: %s",buffer);
testingMethod(buffer);
```

The testing method is:

```
void testingMethod(char *string) {
    char *button = "mystring";
    printf("myString: %s-", string);
    printf("strcmp: %i", strcmp(myString,button));
...
}
```

Output:

```
String at start: mystring
string: mystring
-strcmp: 13 //NOTE the - on the nextline.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a remaining newline character (`'\n'`) in your string. You just have to remove it:

```
#include <string.h>

/* Gets a pointer to the last newline character in the string. */
char *pend=strrchr(string, '\n');

/* Avoids the undefined behavior by checking pend against NULL. */
if(pend!=NULL) *pend='\0';
```

Comment: Behavior still the same, output 13 + the new line before the -. I tried changing \r for \n, but this also crash the program. Same with Daniel Fischer answer.

Comment: My bad, problem was again my printing.

Answer (score 1):

13 is the ASCII value of `'\r'`, so you have a trailing carriage return. You can either add an `'\r'` - and very probably also an `'\n'` - to one,

```
char *button = "mystring\r\n";
```

or remove it from the other to get equality when comparing.

Comment: I tried adding the \r\n to the string, but program will crash when comparing. If i take off the \r it still gives 3, but doesn't crash. Any idea why?

Comment: What happens if you set `char *button = "mystring\r";`? (I sort of expect you get a `-10` result.) Normally, a crash would hint at one argument to `strcmp` not being 0-terminated, but the one `button` points to certainly is, and the passed-in `buffer` should be too, since you `bzero(256)` and only `read` 255 bytes, so it doesn't seem to be that. Try more debugging output, `for(int i = 0; i < 256 && string[i]; ++i) { printf("%d: %d\n", i, string[i]); }` to see what you got (and maybe where it crashes).

Comment: Mange to fix it, was more of a problem on the printing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good. Have you found out what caused the crash? I'm surprised by that.

Comment: Was a function call after the string was accepted, but the printout was not "flush".

Answer (score 0):

Run your program in gdb with a break on the strcmp line, then you can do print /x myString and print /x button and visually compare the two. There will be a difference.